# extract only the substring after double quotes - grep

Tags: sed, grep, perl

I have a file which is as below.

```
<a href="http://firstlink.com" title="title1">
<a href="http://secondlink.com" title="title2">
<a href="http://thirdlink.com" title="title3">
<a href="http://fourthlink.com" title="title4">
```

I am trying to extract only the URLs from the above file. I am using the below command.

```
grep -o '\".*\"' new.txt
```

However, the above command gives me the output as,

```
"http://firstlink.com" title="title1">
"http://secondlink.com" title="title2">
"http://thirdlink.com" title="title3">
"http://foruthlink.com" title="title4">
```

I am trying to extract only the URLs without the `""`. So, my expected output is,

```
http://firstlink.com
http://secondlink.com
http://thirdlink.com
http://fourthlink.com
```

How should I change the grep command? Or is it possible to do it in perl, awk or sed command?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `awk`.

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}' filename
```

would produce the desired output.

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/' filename
```

Using `grep`:

```
grep -oP '[^"]*"\K[^"]*' filename
```

Comment: The `\K` is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573989/318765

Comment: The grep command returns too much. Eg. also title=.

Answer (score 12):

regexp, stream editors and interpreters are overkill here.
Use the old good **cut** :

```
cut -d \" -f 2 < filename
```

Comment: I agree, this is exactly what `cut` was designed for.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/.*"\(http.*\)" .*/\1/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more portable, since some of the other answers depend on href being the first element

```
grep -o href.*\" file.txt | cut -d \" -f 2
```